# Probability of at least two events occuring (custom dice)

Tags: probability

Say we have custom-marked 6-sided die: 1-2-3 is marked as a toad, 4-5 - as a bird, 6 - as a monkey.

So, what is probability of rolling both toad and monkey rolling 4 dice?

I'm totally confused with this example.

Comment: Welcome on Math.se! What have you done so far? Show us your work.

Comment: I know this site is about mathematics, not about English grammar, but ... "dice" is already plural, so there are no "dices". The singular is "die" (which you got correct).

Comment: Hi Nikita

I'm not much into math or anything (i need the answer for practical purposes) but let's see what i have.

I can roughly calculate probability of 'at least one' on 4-dice rolls. Monkey would be P = 1 - (5/6)^4 = 0.52

But i don't get how to calculate 'at least two' cases. Maybe you can provide me with formula or example of some sort?

Comment: Thanks for correcting me, bubba, i'll remember that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of doing this would be using the [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle#In_probability).

It is indeed easier to calcuate the odds of not rolling both a toad and a monkey.

If we write $A$ for the event that we didn't roll a monkey and $B$ for the event that we didn't roll a toad. Then the event $A\cup B$ is the event that we didn't roll a toad or didn't roll a monkey.

Inclusion-exclusion tells us that $$P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B)$$

Now $A\cap B$ is just the event where we didn't roll any monkeys or toads.
We can compute all three values on the right hand side easily.
$$\begin{align}
P(A) &= (\frac{5}{6})^4 \\ 
P(B) &= (\frac{3}{6})^4 \\
P(A\cap B) &= (\frac{2}{6})^4
\end{align}$$

And therefore $P(A\cup B) = (\frac{5}{6})^4 + (\frac{3}{6})^4 - (\frac{2}{6})^4 = \frac{690}{1296} \approx 0.53 $

Now the odds of rolling both a monkey and a toad are $1-P(A\cup B) = \frac{606}{1296} \approx 0.47$.

Comment: Thank you very much Jorik, sure I'll read about inclusion-exclusion. I calculated odds for monkey + toad on 3 dice, getting 0.33, so it works.